# Office Outlook, enable gif animation

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, gif

At work, when I receive an `animated gif`, it displays the animation, but at home it is like a static picture (no animation).
Is there any option/registry key to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Outlook 2003 running on both computers, or is your home running Outlook 2007?

Office 2003 supports animated .gif files, but 2007 doesnt. See [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/107):

> There is no support for animated gif-files when composing or reading an email. If you want to see the animation you’ll need to open the message in a browser. To do this;
>
> Double click the message to open it in its own window. Then choose Other Actions-> View in Browser. This will open the message in Internet Explorer.

If the animated .gif is not showing on Outlook 2003, you can try following these steps, but I am not sure if they will work or not:

1. Open Word
2. Go to Options
3. Then click the 'General' tab
4. Enable "Provide feedback with Animation"
5. Press Save/Ok/Close/whatever

Comment: And the reason is: Outlook 2003 was using the Internet Explorer engine to display your messages. But because this will increase the attack vectors for Outlook, they decided that Outlook 2007 should have its own HTML Mail renderer.